# How to use "bmesh.ops.subdivide_edges" on selected edges

Tags: python, scripting, bmesh

I need to cut an edge into equal parts via script.
Using the standart subdivide is out of question because i will need more then 100 cuts (und using subdivide several times to achieve this is not possible with certain numbers.. e.g. prime numbers).
bmesh.ops.subdivide_edges has no max for the number of cuts but i have problems finding out how to use it only with selected edges. (I am only able to use it an all edges at once)
The only workaround i coul imagine would be to extrude a vertex many times (i am not sure if floating point precision would become an issue tho). I feel lost (and the 100 cut cap of subdivide feels a bit like a bad joke).

Hope somebody can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are doing edit operations

Make sure you are using bmesh.from_edit _mesh to get the selected edge information. When doing from_mesh all edges will be selected.

```
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(my_mesh)
selected_edges = [edge for edge in bm.edges if edge.select]
bmesh.ops.subdivide_edges(bm, edges=selected_edges, cuts=100)
bmesh.update_edit_mesh(my_mesh)
```

Note that .faces has an .active helper property what does this for faces. A similar API for edges is not available, hence you need to use the list comprehension.

Comment: Thx, that does work... :)