# How to subdivide mesh with Python and Blender 2.8?

Tags: python, mesh, scripting

I am trying to find code for subdividing a plane in Blender 2.8, but I don't find it.

I have just created this code but it doesn't work:

```py
import bpy
import bmesh

plane = bpy.data.objects.get("Plane").select_set(True)

bpy.ops.mesh.subdivide(number_cuts = 1)
```

Can you help me?

Comment: This question needs further clarification. What error message do you get when you run this code?

Answer (score 6):

**[`bmesh`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bmesh.html) equivalent**

Using [bmesh](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bmesh.html) can manipulate a mesh in either object or edit mode.

There is generally a bmesh operator equivalent of `bpy.ops.mesh...` in this case

> **[`bmesh.ops.subdivide_edges()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bmesh.ops.html#bmesh.ops.subdivide_edges)**
>
> Subdivide Edges.
>
> Advanced operator for subdividing edges with options for face
>   patterns, smoothing and randomization.

An example of 1 cut subdividing all edges of the context objects mesh.  Select a mesh object run the script in object mode.

```
import bpy
import bmesh

context = bpy.context
ob = context.object
me = ob.data
# New bmesh
bm = bmesh.new()
# load the mesh
bm.from_mesh(me)

# subdivide

bmesh.ops.subdivide_edges(bm,
                          edges=bm.edges,
                          cuts=1,
                          use_grid_fill=True,
                          )

# Write back to the mesh

bm.to_mesh(me)
me.update()
```

To use `bmesh` in edit mode, load the bound edit mesh, (instead of `new` and `from_mesh`)

```
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)
```

write back (instead of `to_mesh`)

```
bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me)
```

[How to use "bmesh.ops.subdivide_edges" on selected edges](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/100138/how-to-use-bmesh-ops-subdivide-edges-on-selected-edges)

[Subdividing cubes at different intervals](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/102207/subdividing-cubes-at-different-intervals)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming this code is being run from a default scene, just after creating a new Plane, your context is incorrect. Subdividing a mesh requires Edit Mode, which can be achieved with the following lines of code:

```py
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode="EDIT")
bpy.ops.mesh.subdivide(number_cuts=1)
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode="OBJECT")
```

Also keep in mind that your plane object must be the *only* object selected, and it also must be active.