# Subdivide and add a Shrink Wrap modifier to an object using python

Tags: python, modifiers, subdivision-surface, shrinkwrap

I am trying to subdivide and finally add a Shrink Wrap modifier to an object using python.

Below is the object SUBDIVIDE code.

```
import bpy
import bmesh
from bpy.props import IntProperty


class SimpleOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "mesh.custom_subdiv"
    bl_label = "Custom Subdiv Mesh Operator"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}
    
    subd_levels: IntProperty(default=10, options={'HIDDEN', 'SKIP_SAVE'})
    
    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.active_object.type=='MESH' and context.mode=='OBJECT'

    def execute(self, context):
        ob = context.object
        me = ob.data
        
        if me.subdiv_prop >= self.subd_levels:
            self.report({'INFO'}, "Maximum reached")
            return {'FINISHED'}
        else:
            bm = bmesh.new()
            bm.from_mesh(me)
            bmesh.ops.subdivide_edges(bm, edges=bm.edges, cuts=self.subd_levels, use_grid_fill=True)
            bm.to_mesh(me)
            me.update()
            self.report({'INFO'}, "{} levels applied".format(self.subd_levels))
            me.subdiv_prop =+ self.subd_levels
            return {'FINISHED'}
        
        
def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(SimpleOperator)
    bpy.types.Mesh.subdiv_prop = IntProperty(default=0)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SimpleOperator)
    del bpy.types.Mesh.subdiv_prop


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

    # test call
    #bpy.ops.mesh.custom_subdiv('INVOKE_DEFAULT')
```

Where do I add the Shrink Wrap code `bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='SHRINKWRAP')` so they can be executed simultaneously?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add modifiers using python script and set parameters?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/71569/how-to-add-modifiers-using-python-script-and-set-parameters)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the low-level function to add modifiers which allows for direct property access: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.ObjectModifiers.html#bpy.types.ObjectModifiers.new

```
import bpy

C = bpy.context

# Get the object
obj = C.scene.objects['Cube']

# Add the modifier using the low level function
shrink_mod = obj.modifiers.new(name="Shrinkie", type='SHRINKWRAP')
shrink_mod.offset = 0.01
shrink_mod.target = C.scene.objects['Sphere']
```

[How to add modifiers using python script and set parameters?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/71569/how-to-add-modifiers-using-python-script-and-set-parameters)

If you want to make it work along with my code from your other question [How to limit number of times an operator can run in python](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/248890/how-to-limit-number-of-times-an-operator-can-run-in-python), add the following lines to the operator:

```
        # Add the modifier using the low level function
        shrink_mod = context.object.modifiers.new(name="Shrinkie", type='SHRINKWRAP')
        shrink_mod.offset = 0.01
        shrink_mod.target = context.scene.objects['Sphere']
```