# Insert new vertices into face using pyhton & bmesh

Tags: python, faces, bmesh

I want to add vertices to a face. Can I only do this by redrawing the whole face with `bmesh.faces.new(loop_vertices)` or can I also just add some to an existing face? The documentation states that the BMVert sequence of a face is read-only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Subdivide an edge or edges.**

Just as with using the UI to add another vertex to a face would require subdividing an edge.

The loop vertices that define a face, will also be a part of another faces loop verts, if connected via an edge.  Bmesh gives us a quick API into  all the loops and linked geometry of each element. In most cases these are read only.

To add a single vert to an existing faces verts, requires subdividing one edge.  Using the [bmesh subdivide edges operator](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bmesh.ops.html#bmesh.ops.subdivide_edges) will ensure that the links and loops are  correctly maintained.

Simple example, using active face and subdividing the zeroth edge.

```
f = bmesh.faces.active # the active face 
bmesh.ops.subdivide_edges(
        bm, # the bmesh
        edges=[f.edges[0]] if f else [], # zeroth edge  if face
        )
```

This will ofcourse add an edge also.  If another face shares the edge it will also share the newly created geometry.

[How to subdivide mesh with Python and Blender 2.8?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/163855/how-to-subdivide-mesh-with-python-and-blender-2-8/163880)

[How to use "bmesh.ops.subdivide_edges" on selected edges](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/100138/how-to-use-bmesh-ops-subdivide-edges-on-selected-edges)

```
import bpy
import bmesh

ob = bpy.context.object
me = ob.data
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)

f = bm.faces.active
e = f.edges[0]

bmesh.ops.subdivide_edges(
    bm,
    edges=[e],
    cuts=1,
    edge_percents={e : 0.33},
    )
    
bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me)
```

Comment: Thank you very much that is very helpful! Is it somehow possible to control the position of the newly created vertex also? Or do I have to do this after the fact?

Comment: For single edge after fact is pretty simple. However Have added example that subs a vert at 33% along edge instead of default 50.  Look to see which is edges first vert for which end.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The first vertex would be the one with the lower index or the one appearing first in BMEdgeSeq?

Comment: IIRC `edge.verts[0]`.  First in edges  BMVertSeq.  Easy enough to test...

Comment: That concludes my question. Thanks you!